# Decrease Chrome time out

Tags: google-chrome, internet

I'm in China at the moment. Every time I go on a webpage with a Like/Tweet button, Chrome spends a few seconds trying to access Facebook/Twitter (which are blocked in China). As a result, pages can take more than 10 seconds to load. Is there a way to decrease the time out or prevent Chrome from trying to access Twitter/Facebook in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit yours [HOSTS file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to prevent your computer from connecting to specified domains. This will affect your *entire* computer, not just Google Chrome.

In your case, you would add:

```
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 twitter.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to install an extension in Chrome which prevents third party trackers and widgets from loading.

[Ghostery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij?hl=en) is a good option for this.